# JQuery find not working for tr element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just wondering if anyone knows why the following code doesn't work (each() is not executed at all)...it works if i try td elements but not tr elements for some reason?

The html is returned by a php script and looks like

```
<tr class="my_files_row"><td>bla</td><td>bla</td></tr>


function update(html)
{
    $(html).find('tr').each(function()
    {
        alert('success');
    })
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you passing in as the 'html' argument? If it happens to be the <tr> element itself then it won't find anything inside itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your php should return the tr inside other element (a table perhaps). As the JQuery documentation states, find searches on "descendants" of the element, and tr is not a descendant of tr in your html. You can change the response to:

```
<table> <tr class="my_files_row"><td>bla</td><td>bla</td></tr> </table>
```

and that should work.

Comment: Thanks all, this was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Find only finds descendants. In your case, tr is the root.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in all TR elements and not those of a particular table/tbody/thead/tfoot element, then ask the right question (and don't be more complicated than you need to be). This:

```
$('tr').each(function(){
  var tr = $(this) ;
  ...
}) ;
```

should do you. If you need to be more specific table, you just to refine your selector:

```
$('table#mySpecialTable tbody tr')
```

The above gives you all  elements in the  of the table with id `mySpecialTable`.